# ASP.NET Core MVC. Несколько Select на одной странице

Tags: c#, razor, asp-net-core-mvc

Представим, что существует три таблицы в БД, в которых записаны названия производителей ПК, ноутбуков и приставок.

Как мне вывести на страницу 3 разных списка select, которые бы отображали информацию из этих таблиц?

Первая моя мысль была, реализовать полиморфный список, который бы создавался в контроллере, а затем, через Razor с помощью условий разбивался на стороне страницы.
Но, что-то мне подсказывает, что существует более элегантный способ сделать это.

Comment: Передавайте во View модель, в которой три (или больше) свойства типа `List<T>` для каждой таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В контроллере описал:

```
tempregion = _context.Regionalities.ToList();
venicles = _context.Venicles.ToList();
whenevaq = _context.WhenEvaquateds.ToList();

ViewBag.ListOfRegion = tempregion;
ViewBag.ListOfVenicle = venicles;
ViewBag.ListOfWhenEvaq = whenevaq;
```

В представлении:

```
<select class="form-control"asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfVenicle, "Id", "TypeOfVenicle"))"></select>

<select class="form-control"asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfWhenEvaq, "Id", "WhenEvaq"))"></select>
```